# Accessing and filtering data in nested array of objects in PHP

Tags: php

I use an api of League Of Legends, i would get the summoners stats.

I am using an API of League of Legends to get summoners stats.

The code:

```
object(stdClass)[3]
 public 'summonerId' => int XXXXXXXXXXX
  public 'playerStatSummaries' => 
    array (size=15)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[4]
      public 'playerStatSummaryType' => string 'AramUnranked5x5' (length=15)
      public 'wins' => int 100
      public 'modifyDate' => float 1412611932000
      public 'aggregatedStats' => 
        object(stdClass)[5]
          ...
```

I want to get data ONLY when the value of "Playerstatsummarytype" is "RankedSolo5x5".

I've been trying to use this:

```
$win_ranked = $parsed_json2->{'playerStatSummaries'}[8]->{'wins'};
$losses_ranked = $parsed_json2->{'playerStatSummaries'}[8]->{'losses'};
```

But with certain summoners, sometimes the number is 8 or 9.

So how do I get data ONLY when "Playerstatsummarytype" is RankedSolo5x5.

Thanks =)

Comment: There is no JSON here.

Comment: That looks like a var_dump not JSON to me....

Comment: Yes, i use var_dump(json_decode($json2));

Comment: _“I want get data ONLY when "Playerstatsummarytype" is RankedSolo5x5”_ – well then you have to access that property first, and compare its value … and only use the rest of the data, if it matches what you’re looking for.

Comment: What's with the use of `{}` syntax here?  Very odd unless you are trying to access properties bases on variable name like `$object->{$some_property}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like you simply need to filter the array at `$parsed_json2->playerStatSummaries`.

That should be simple:

```
$filtered_array = array_filter($parsed_json2->playerStatSummaries, function($item) {
    return ($item->playerStatSummaryType === 'RankedSolo5x5');
});
// now you can get at wins/losses for items in filtered array like:
foreach ($filtered_array as $obj) {
    echo 'Wins: ' . $obj->wins;
    echo 'Losses: ' . $obj->losses;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, i have try to make a varibable ( $wins_ra_3 = all wins and $win_lo_3 = all losses ) because i need to calculate.

//On calcule toutes les ranked
function total_r($win_ranked, $losses_ranked) {
 return $win_ranked + $losses_ranked;
}
//On fait la division
function Pourcentage($Nombre, $Total) {
 return $Nombre * 100 / $Total;
}
$total_r =  total_r($win_ranked, $losses_ranked); //Toutes les ranked
$Winrate =  Pourcentage($win_ranked, $total_r); //On calcule le WinRate

How get my result ? Ty =)

Comment: @MoundirOP I not clear on what you are asking.  If you have a follow coding question, you may want to open a new question.